# AppEngine nodejs : how to protect a cron URL from public access?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron

> A cron handler is just a normal handler defined in app.yaml. You can
>   prevent users from accessing URLs used by scheduled tasks by
>   restricting access to administrator accounts.

However this option is not available in nodejs. What's the recommended way to protect a CRON URL from public access with the nodejs runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if your request contains

```
X-Appengine-Cron: true
```

> The X-Appengine-Cron header is set internally by Google App Engine. If
>   your request handler finds this header it can trust that the request
>   is a cron request. If the header is present in an external user
>   request to your app, it is stripped, except for requests from logged
>   in administrators of the application, who are allowed to set the
>   header for testing purposes.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests

This can be done e.g. like this:

```
app.get('/my-cron-trigger', async (req, res, next) => {
  // ensure that request comes from cron
  if (req.header('x-appengine-cron') !== 'true') {
    next();
    return;
  }

  // [your function code]
}
```